# PHP mysql inserted date and time incorrect by using PHP syntax

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I tried to INSERT and UPDATE my databases with date and time. When I update or insert date and time always insert incorrect values. I am in Sri Lanka.

I already insert following line in php.ini file according to [their recommendations](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file).

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Colombo"
```

Example of incorrect values.

**Accrual local date and time** - 2017-04-17 00:01:05 (12:01 A.M)
**1.When I use `NOW()`, insert database date and time** - 2017-04-17 14:30:16
**2.When I use `CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'Asia/Colombo')`, insert database date and time** - 2017-04-17 20:01:05

Before I update php.ini file also get incorrect date and time values to my sql database.

PHP date information get like this,

```
date.default_latitude - 31.7667
date.default_longitude - 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith - 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith - 90.583333
date.timezone - Asia/Colombo
```

Those latitude and longitude are not in colombo, sri lanka.

PHP Code:
1. Using NOW(),

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET ip='$ip', lastlogin=NOW() WHERE usernames='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
```

2. Using CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'Asia/Colombo'),

   $sql = "UPDATE users SET ip='$ip', lastlogin=CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'Asia/Colombo') WHERE usernames='$db_username' LIMIT 1";

Comment: there's no mysql here, there's also no php

Comment: May be server have some different configurations.

Comment: @O. Jones how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using like this,

```
CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', '+09:30')
```

Accrual Asia/Colombo time difference is +5:30h. When I add `CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'Asia/Colombo')`, it shows 4 hours less time therefore I add additional 4 hours to converter and it is add +9:30 hours to server time.

I think my inmotion server have not a UTC time. It has something else time because when I update my database using NOW() PHP code it shows 15:17 time but UTC time was 19:17 time.